# The SHA-256 digest not supported for MGF1 on Android using RSA OAEP decryption?

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, rsa

I'm working with a protocol that uses an algorithm which creates RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding encrypted messages. For example, this [Apple algorithm](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seckeyalgorithm/2091907-rsaencryptionoaepsha256aesgcm).

I have the following code

```kotlin
class RsaOaep {

    private val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation)

    companion object {
        // Results in "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"
        private const val transformation = "$KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA/$BLOCK_MODE_ECB/$ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP"

        // Note that MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256 is not supported on Android!!!
        private val spec = OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256","MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)
    }

    fun wrap(publicKey: Key, data: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val secretKey = SecretKeyGenerator().generateSecretKey()
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey, spec)
        return cipher.wrap(secretKey)
    }

    fun decrypt(wrappedKey: ByteArray, privateKey: Key): ByteArray {
        cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, privateKey, spec)
        return cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, SecretKeyGenerator.KEY_ALGORITHM, Cipher.SECRET_KEY)
    }
}
```

But my Android application can't decrypt them. I'm getting the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 9813
    java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi$OAEPWithMGF1Padding.initAlgorithmSpecificParameters(AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi.java:228)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:147)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2980)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1288)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1223)
        at com.example.RsaOaep.decrypt(RsaOaep.kt:21)
```

This limitation is hardcoded into the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/keystore/java/android/security/keystore2/AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi.java#228).

- Why is that the case?
- When will it change? ... and
- How can I work around it?

Comment: This simply seems to be a bug. A similar bug is [#36708951](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36708951), which also mentions the behavior you describe in a comment, [#23](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36708951#comment23). Presumably there is a relation between the two bugs, however it is not clear, so you could also file your bug and refer to the existing bug.

Comment: For working around it: try and use the same code but by using a relatively new Bouncy Castle library installed (using `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()` ) and referenced during `Cipher.getInstance`...

Comment: Also note that the bug only occurs in combination with the AndroidKeyStore. There is no problem if the key is not from the AndroidKeyStore.

Comment: @Topaco That along with the `javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider()` in the stack trace implies to me that the decryption might succeed should the cipher be created with a specific provider instead of relying on the default provider, or by using encrypt/decrypt modes instead of wrap/unwrap modes.

Comment: I am using the AndroidKeyStore to use the StrongBox, so I'm not sure that using a different provider will work.